# MATLAB GUI - Making Checkbox Global

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox, global

I have a `MATLAB GUI` which gives options to tick for the user. Every tick has a different mathematical significance. After user ticks something the calculation will be done after they press to 'Calculate'.

My main formula under Calculate button is:

```
effective_weight = weight + pilotsw + fo_weight  %pilots weight & first officer's weight
```

`pilots_weight` & `fo_weight` has different checkboxes and they have the following code:

```
function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to checkbox2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of checkbox2
% --- Executes on button press in checkbox3.

if (get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))

pilotw = -100

else

 pilotw = 0

end
```

global pilotw  (and same for first officers's check box)

and pilotw is a global variable for calculate function.

Aim is to change the effective weight and do the rest of computations accordingly if the pilot is there (or not).

Comment: And what exactly is your problem / question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the global variable `pilotw`, you need to declare it as such in your function:

```
function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

        %'Declare global variable'
        global pilotw

        %'Set global variable'
        if get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max')
                pilotw = -100

        else
                pilotw = 0
        end;
end
```

Comment: Yes this has helped. And pilotw should be initialized in the beginning of the code. (i.e pilotw = 0)

Answer (score 0):

You need declare   global pilotw in each function you want to use this variable.